# Custom Bean Class for GUI Component in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

Alright so my professor posted up an assignment but the reference code that we're supposed to use is confusing me. He made a JFrame and inside that Jframe he put in a button, but the beanclass for that button is the subclass JHoverButton.Java which extends JButton. When I try to do that in my code, I can't get the Bean Class to be my own sub class. I've tried custom creation code, I've tried binding and I've looked around on stack overflow but I couldn't really find an answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This is what my teacher posted [image: This is what my teacher posted]

This is where I'm stuck.[image]

Any help would really be appreciated, thank you!

Source Code for BeanProjectTest.Java:

```
package beanproject;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.*;


 public class BeanProjectTest extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/**
 * Creates new form BeanProjectTest
 */
public BeanProjectTest() {
    initComponents();
    try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        //UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
        MetalLookAndFeel.setCurrentTheme(new DefaultMetalTheme());
        SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);

    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.toString());
    }
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jColorChooser1 = new javax.swing.JColorChooser();
    jHoverButton1 = new beanproject.JHoverButton();
    jIntegerField1 = new beanproject.JIntegerField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Bean Project Test");

    jHoverButton1.setText("jHoverButton1");

    jIntegerField1.setText("jIntegerField1");

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(38, 38, 38)
            .addComponent(jHoverButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(53, 53, 53))
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jIntegerField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 163, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jHoverButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGap(72, 72, 72)
            .addComponent(jIntegerField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(241, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */

    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new BeanProjectTest().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JColorChooser jColorChooser1;
private beanproject.JHoverButton jHoverButton1;
private beanproject.JIntegerField jIntegerField1;
// End of variables declaration
```

}

Source Code For JHoverButton.Java:

```
public class JHoverButton extends JButton implements MouseListener{

public JHoverButton(){
    super();
    initialize();
}

private void initialize(){
    setBorderPainted(false);
    addMouseListener(this);
}

public JHoverButton(String text){
    super(text);
    initialize();
}

public JHoverButton(String text, Icon icon){
    super(text, icon);
    initialize();
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled){
    super.setEnabled(enabled);
    if(enabled){
        if(isBorderPainted()){
            setBorderPainted(false);
            repaint();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
   if(!isBorderPainted() && isEnabled()){
       setBorderPainted(true);
       repaint();
   }
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    if(isBorderPainted()){
        setBorderPainted(false);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Done, I pasted the code for JHoberButton.Java and BeanProjectTest.Java

Comment: for public class JHoverButton extends JButton implements MouseListener{ to search in method implemented in ButtonModel rather than bothering with mouse events

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a starter please note that adding a third-party component would be really easier if you code your GUI by hand instead of using a GUI builder:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(new JHoverButton("Hello!"));
...
frame.add(panel);
```

Now having said that, instead of adding a JButton from the palette you need to add a new Bean and specify the full path to your component: `packagename.ComponentName`.

#### 1. Select Choose Bean option

[image: Beans palette]

#### 2. Choose the appropriate bean by inserting the Class' full path

[image: Choose bean]

#### 3. Place the JHoverButton component

[image: Place JHoverButton]

#### 4. Inspect Bean's properties

[image: JHoverButton properties]

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out! :D

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on JHoverButton.java file
2. CTRL+C
3. Click on your JPanel in designer view
4. CTRL+V

source: http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqFormUsingCustomComponent

Comment: I can't, that part is generated code and it's not editable. The same with the variable declarations at the bottom.

Comment: hmmm... click on your left button and copy it.

Comment: That created a new variable called jHoverButton2 with the same properties. I don't get how my professor got it to use the subclass instead of JButton to begin with.

Comment: I guess that would work, but my teacher said to make a subclass of Jtextfield that limits the input to decimal numbers only, so I want to see if there is a way to do that without copying and pasting his stuff you know?

Comment: So create JTextField and CTRL+C and paste your TextField to pane, where is the problem?